# Why the same jsp is generating different htm in local and Server

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have one ApprovalProcess.jsp which displays the list of approvals. The id of the approval when clicked takes you to ApprovalProcessDetails.jsp which displays the approval details and buttons like Approve Reject and Back.
In my local when i am clicking on the approval id it is going to the next page.
But in the QA Server when it is clicked it is not going to the next page.

I checked the developer tool for any errors and it shows the following error
    Uncaught ReferenceError: validateForm is not defined
    at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit (ApprovalProcess.htm:447)
    at oamSubmitForm (ApprovalProcess.htm:172)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (ApprovalProcess.htm:475)

Now i checked the ApprovalProcess.htm in my local and that has this validateForm method in script.
But when i check the ApprovalProcess.htm in the Server it does not have that script section.

How come the same jsp is generating different htm in local and server.

```
So this is the part where that validateForm method is called and the commandLink when we click on the id to go to the next page

[ApprovalProcessjsp][1]

This is the doViewDetail method in page bean

[doViewDetails][2]

This is the script part which is missing in the server htm and is present in the local htm

[MissingScript][3]
```

Expected result is to have the same htm in local and server
Actual result is that the htm is not same in local and server

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Answer (score 0):

Function declarations will have local scope. (like `var` statements)

If I understood you properly, all the code must be wrapped in an `onload` which means your `validateForm` method is not accessible from HTML markup.

Try writing your `validateForm` function before `window.onload`